# Web Notifications custom implementation vs third-party services

Tags: onesignal, web-notifications, pushpad

I need to implement web notifications for some website and send notifications from php script executed in console.

I found that is possible to implement web notifications without using third-party services, by using this lib https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php
Here is good tutorial
https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/

But there also are some third-party services that provides sending web notifications, like:

`https://onesignal.com/webpush
https://pushalert.co/
https://pushpad.xyz/`

and others.

1 - What benefits from using this third party services ?

2 - Is there some limitations when this feature is implemented without using these third-party services ?

3 - How third-party services send notifications, are they using they own push service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - What benefits from using this third party services ?
  - you don't have to manage the service.
  - You Don't have to work on modifications, if there is any update in backends.
  - You don't have to actually look for cross browser issues.
  - Easy to implement
  - You will get Reporting along with this (few gives)

2 - Is there some limitations when this feature is implemented without using these third-party services ?
  - Limitation will be on membership level, If you choose highest paid membership then there will no limitations attached.

3 - How third-party services send notifications, are they using they own push service ?
  - They Have their managed backends and for frontends they use the same JS function but well written and optimized.